How to remove a project reference in Rider?
In one of my projects MyProject I've added a reference to another project called OpenAI using right click - Add - Reference...
Now I want to remove this reference, but when I check Add - Reference, it gives no option to remove the reference:

So, how to remove the reference to the OpenAI project?

found it in Dependencies - .NET 8.0 - Projects - OpenAI, right click - Delete  (maybe it was Edit - Delete, I don't remember)

You can also edit csproj and remove it manually.
